# nested_form_fields gem vs cocoon

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, for-loop, field

I'm building an app with nested forms and wish to dynamically add fields using jquery.

There are two gems that I've heard people talk about. One is nested_form_fields, the other cocoon.

Has anyone compared both gems and have a strong preference for either?

https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are pretty much identical and do the same thing. I recommend watching [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) in order for you to better understand what is going on behind the scenes, when you use these gems and even teach yourself on how to achieve the desired result without any additional gem dependencies.